# Cannot add property target, object is not extensible

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

this is module of MarketElement:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import {Tabs} from "antd";
import MarketEvent from './MarketEvent';
import TakeOutEvent from './TakeOutEvent';
import PaymentEvent from './PaymentEvent';
import FullReduce from './FullReduce'

const TabPane = Tabs.TabPane;

class RouteContent {

public static allList: RouteContent[] = [
    new RouteContent('marketMain'),
    new RouteContent('fullReduce')
];
public id: string;
public name: string;
public target: JSX.Element;

public constructor(id: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.Content(id);
}


public Content(id:string):any {
    console.log('传到了父组件：',id);
    switch (id) {
        case 'marketMain':
            this.target = <MarketEvent getName={this.Content}/>;
            break;
        case 'fullReduce':
            this.target = <FullReduce getName={this.Content} />;
            break;
    }
}}

export default class MarketElement extends React.Component<any> {


public state = {
    // target: RouteContent.Content('marketMain')
    target: RouteContent.allList[0]

};

public getChangePage = (passName: string) => {
    this.setState({
        name: passName
    })
};

public componentWillMount(){
    console.log('componentWillMount MarketElement');
}

public componentDidMount(){
    console.log('componentDidMount MarketElement');
}



public render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <Tabs defaultActiveKey="0">
                <TabPane tab="活动管理" key="0">{this.state.target.target}</TabPane>
                <TabPane tab="外卖设置" key="1"><TakeOutEvent/></TabPane>
                <TabPane tab="支付设置" key="2"><PaymentEvent/></TabPane>
            </Tabs>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

this is module of MarketEvent:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import './MarketEvent.less'

interface MarketEventProps {
   getName: any;
}

export default class MarketEvent extends React.Component<MarketEventProps,any> {

public constructor(props:any) {
    super(props);
}

public componentWillMount(){
    console.log('componentWillMount MarketEvent');
}

public componentDidMount(){
    console.log('componentDidMount MarketEvent');
}

public refName = (name:string) => {
    this.props.getName(name);
};

public render(){
    return(
        <div className="market_event">
            <div className="market_top">
                营销活动
            </div>
            <div className="market_body">
                <ul className="market_ul">
                    <li onClick={this.refName.bind(this,'fullReduce')}><a href="javascript:;"><span className="l1">减</span>
                        <div className="event_box">
                            <h2>店铺满减</h2>
                            <i>促销</i><i>客单价</i>
                            <p>下单满足条件可享受减免</p>
                        </div>
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;"><span className="l2">店</span>
                        <div className="event_box">
                            <h2>店铺代金券</h2>
                            <i>拉新</i><i>引流</i>
                            <p>进店时可领取店铺专用代金券</p>
                        </div>
                    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;"><span className="l3">促</span>
                        <div className="event_box">
                            <h2>折扣促销</h2>
                            <i>新品</i><i>爆款</i>
                            <p>下单满足条件可享受减免</p>
                        </div>
                    </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

}
```

this is module of FullReduce:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Button} from "antd";

interface FullReduceProps {
    getName: any
}

export default class FullReduce extends React.Component<FullReduceProps,any> {

public componentWillMount(){
    console.log('componentWillMount  FullReduce');

}

public componentDidMount(){
    console.log('componentDidMount  FullReduce')
}
public refName = (name:string) => {
    this.props.getName(name);
};

public render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <Button htmlType='button' onClick={this.refName.bind(this,'marketMain')}>返回</Button>
            已经进入了店铺满减页面了
        </div>
    )
}

}
```

The effect I want to achieve is  clicked this one item in module of MarketEvent,Then switch to the contents of the corresponding list items, that is module of FullReduce.Then go back from FullReduce to the previous page.But when I click on one item, it will report it wrong：Cannot add property target, object is not extensible；I don't know why,
please  help me ,thanks 
[image]

Comment: no pictures please, add the code properly

Comment: ok,thanks your suggest

Comment: Can you take a look at it for me?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `Content` method (a method name should not start with an uppercase letter) seems to be changing the `target` member of the `RouteContent` class.

Since you're passing this method as a callback you need to bind it inside `RouteContent':

```
class RouteContent {

    public id: string;
    public name: string;
    public target: JSX.Element;

    public constructor(id: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.Content = this.Content.bind(this);
        this.Content(id);
    }

    ....

}
```

This way, `this` into Content will consistently refer to the desired `RouteContent` instance. And Javascript won't complain about Object not being extensible.
Your code may have other issues regarding Component state management but it will fix the asked problem.